# How to do naming system with RMI in different hosts?

Tags: java, dns, rmi

I have two java classes one is the client and the other is the server, in the client I have to give the server ip address, but I want to make it dynamique so the client knows the ip of a third machine(naming system) which search for the method (like DNS) and returns the ip address of the specific server who provides this method.

Edited:

classe client :

```
public class Client {
private Client() {}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
    try {
        //Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.9",1091);

        Calculator stub = (Calculator) registry.lookup("Hello");

        String response = stub.add(4,2);
        System.out.println("response: " + response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

server :

```
public class Server implements Calculator{

public Server() {}

public String add(int a,int b) {
    return "Hello, a+b= "+(a+b);
}
public String sub(int a,int b) {
    return "Hello, a-b= "+(a-b);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Server obj = new Server();
        Calculator stub = (Calculator) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

        // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1091);
        registry.bind("Hello", stub);

        System.err.println("Server ready");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide your code or what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't know what's 'too broad' about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with the RMI Registry. Only a process running in the same host as the Registry can bind to it. You would have to use a different naming service such as LDAP.

However the rest of your description is what RMI already does. You look up a name in the Registry and it returns you a stub that knows how to communicate with the corresponding remote object.

Comment: so i have to implement LDAP and put it in separate machine  so the client adress it,  and it returns the right ip address of the server to the client

Comment: It's simpler than that. Just use the LDAP server as a Registry. Bind the remote object to the LDAP server; have the client lookup the LDAP server to get the stub, and then call the remone method. RMI takes care of the IP address for you.